# How I spit the line by \n

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split the line by `\n`.

```
a = "Id, Name, Age, Address\n123,John,23,\"No:23 21st street\n areacode\npincode\"\n124,Antony,25,\"No:213 29th street\n areacode\npincode\"\n"
```

After splitting the line by \n, the line should be like this.

```
a = ["Id, Name, Age, Address", "123,John,23,\"No:23 21st street\n areacode\npincode\"", "124,Antony,25,\"No:213 29th street\n areacode\npincode\"]
```

The commands I tried

```
a.scan(/(?!\B"[^"]*)^C?(?:[\n\r]+|\z)(?![^"]*"\B)/)
a.scan(/.+?(?:[\n\r]+|\z)/)
```

Comment: Why the "using regexp" requirement?

Comment: I am facing a similar kind of issue in my project for which the requirement is using regex

Comment: We know how you spit [sic], which I have no idea how it is relevant to programming at all. By the say, what is your question?

Comment: _"using regex"_ is somehow meaningless. How is the regex being used?

Comment: I tried `a.scan(/.+?(?:[\n\r]+|\z)/)`, it splits address also. My line should be like `"123,John,23,\"No:23 21st street\n areacode\npincode\""`

Comment: @MohamedRafiqP: use the csv class: `require 'csv'` and then `CSV.parse(a)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me

Comment: `CSV.parse` works for you although the requirement is to use regex?

Comment: This question should not have been closed, there is absolutely nothing unclear about it. The requirement is clear, what have been tried is clear, the desired result is clear.

Comment: If that string contain space, instead of comma, the `CSV.parse(a)` didn't work. `CSV.parse(a, col_sep: " ")` also not work.

Comment: For example: `a = "Hi \"Hello Hi\""` means `a` is `Hi "Hello Hi"` but if I use `CSV.parse` then take an array value and join by space. That string changed like this `Hi Hello Hi`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use the [split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method from [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html)?

```
a = "Id, Name, Age, Address\n123,John,23,\"No:23 21st street\n areacode\npincode\"\n124,Antony,25,\"No:213 29th street\n areacode\npincode\"\n"

a.split "\n"

["Id, Name, Age, Address", "123,John,23,\"No:23 21st street", " areacode", "pincode\"", "124,Antony,25,\"No:213 29th street", " areacode", "pincode\""]
```